# Android Studio debug build to device makes device disconnect

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

**Disclaimer**: I'm not a professional Android developer so it could be that there's some basic things that I don't know about, but I've really tried everything I could think of and find, and I'm now running out of ideas (and sanity)

---

To begin with, I'm experiencing the following problem appeared on

- Mac OS 10.15.1
- Android Studio 4.0 Beta 5

I've been having no issues building debug builds (for phones) for my project up until yesterday where I decided I wanted to try a build to a tablet.

On my first attempt I got the error below, and after that building to any other physical device gives me the same issue.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '.../android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'device '1c34fab8140c7ece' not found'
```

As soon as I get this error the device disappears from the device list, and at the same time I get the prompt to `Allow USB debugging`, and I have to disconnect the device and plug it in again for it to show up in Android Studio

**What I have tried:**

- Restarting Android Studio
- Restarting the computer
- Tried different cables (both USB-C and Micro-USB)
- Updating the build tools to the latest version
- Reinstalling the build tools
- Upgrading and downgrading Android Studio
- Building different projects (both Native and Flutter)
- Enabling and disabling USB debugging
- Restarting `adb` (several times)
- Building to a device I've never used before

When connecting the device I sometimes also get an notice saying the following as well as prompting me to install the Android File Transfer application, which I've also done, but that also did nothing noticeable

> The connected device can't access data on your phone. Reconnect the USB cable and try again

Looking in the Logcat after attempting a build I see this entry: `2020-04-24 14:48:40.646 21813-19620/? E/MtpServer: Failed to start usb driver!`, but I don't find a lot of information about this problem

Just to be sure I've also tried just building the projects to a normal emulator so that there's nothing with my recent code changes that is causing this, and everything builds fine.

I will be really happy and grateful with any clues or tips on how I can proceed as I've already spent hours trying to figure this out

Comment: `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: I've tried restarting it several times, but as soon as I run build the same problem shows up, I'm feeling more and more that the issue is related to the `MtpServer: Failed to start usb driver!` message that at least I haven't seen before, but I can't find much information about it and not sure what I could do to fix it

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @SalahAdDin It's solved, but I don't remember what I did, or if it could have even resolved by itself.. what I see in my git history is that around that time I decided to add some Flutter stuff to the project, so it could be that there's something in the project configuration or cache that got fixed when adding Flutter which might have some settings that was outdated in my project

Answer (score 0):

-firstly, always must allow **usb debugging**.
-after connected to computer or laptop **click on file transfer** in your mobile phone if option available.
-may be you get prompt for asking installation for an app so **click on install**.

-must install mobile drivers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have had no problems building for months so this is a new problem. I'm not sure which drivers I would need to install, do you have some more information on this?

Comment: your phone drivers search o internet for you phone